# Is there a more efficient way instead of multiple FOR loops and IF statements?

Tags: python

I have the below code snippet:

```
for item1 in filesName :
    for item2 in finalName :
        if item1.split('.',1)[0].split('--', 1)[0] == item2.split('.',1)[0].split('--', 1)[0] :
            for eachFile in os.listdir(src) :
                if eachFile == item1 :
                
                    # rename files
                    os.rename(os.path.join(src, item1), os.path.join(src, item2))

                    # move files
                    shutil.move(os.path.join(src, item2), os.path.join(dst, item2))
            
                else :
                    logger.error(error_message)
                    raise ValueError(error_message)

FilesName = ['01-01-2001 Active File Name.xlsx', '01-01-2001 Inactive File Name.xlsx']

FinalName = ['01-01-2001 Active File Name--CORRECTION1.xlsx']
```

What it intends to do is rename an existing file in case of a correction - for example, I have a file called 'File Name.xlsx', but I want to rename it to 'File Name --CORRECTION1.xlsx' - it matches the file to each other and renames it.

The code works as intended, however my limited experience tells me that I'm using too many FOR loops and IF statements, and there's probably a better way [performance wise] to do it.

So what's my question - **is there a better solution?**

Comment: The wording of your question is unclear to me. Wat does renaming have to do with "matching files to each other"?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of values for `filesName` and `finalName`?

Comment: @BeniTrainor I have updated the question with an example.

Comment: @RolandSmith Imagine I processed one file, but found an error and need to process it again. If I don't rename the file being reprocessed it will replace the already existing one (from the 1st time). I don't want that, so I need to rename it. To do that, I must first find its match and then I can rename it.

Comment: @timgeb That would already help in terms of looking more clean, thank you!

Comment: As soon one file goes through the inner else clause everything stops leaving work half done. Is this really what you want to do?

Comment: Hey @datascientistwannabe, could you also specify sample values for `src` and `dst` to make the code executable without Exceptions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
FilesName = ['01-01-2001 Active File Name.xlsx', '01-01-2001 Inactive File Name.xlsx']
FinalName = ['01-01-2001 Active File Name--CORRECTION1.xlsx']

# Helper function to clean up the splitting
get_base_name = lambda x: x.split('.',1)[0].split('--', 1)[0]

# Remove the two first loops by checking for base name matches
# using set intersection
filesName_base = {get_base_name(x) for x in FilesName}
finalName_base = {get_base_name(x) for x in FinalName}
files_to_change_base = filesName_base.intersection(finalName_base)

# Potential candidates of files to be changed
files_to_change = [x for x in FilesName if get_base_name(x) in files_to_change_base]

# No need to call this on each iteration of the inner loop
files_in_dir = set(os.listdir(src))

for file_to_change in files_to_change:
    if file_to_change in files_in_dir:
        # rename files
        os.rename(os.path.join(src, item1), os.path.join(src, item2))
        # move files
        shutil.move(os.path.join(src, item2), os.path.join(dst, item2))

    else :
        logger.error(error_message)
        raise ValueError(error_message)
```

Edit: Removed another for loop by just looping once and checking if the files are in the directory. `files_in_dir` is moved into a set because set membership is a O(1) operation as opposed to O(n).

Comment: You could go one step further and use another set intersection to find the matches with `os.listdir(src)` to remove another for loop. Let me know if it's unclear how to do so.

Comment: @datascientistwannabe I did a small edit to get rid of one more loop

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no need to loop over all the files in the directory to find out if a file with a particular name already exists.

If I can guess at all as to what you are actually trying to accomplish, the code which writes a new file might currently look like

```
### FIXME: don't overwrite if outputfile exists
with open(outputfile, "w") as output:
    output.write(data)
```

and you'd change that to, say,

```
idx = 1
# base is outputfile without .xslx
base = outputfile[:-5]
while os.path.exists(outputfile):
    outputfile = "%s--CORRECTION%i.xlsx" % (base, idx)
    idx += 1

with open(outputfile, "w" ...
```

The loop updates the number after `--CORRECTION` until it lands on a number which isn't already taken by an existing file. (If you delete a file somewhere in the middle of that sequence, the code will obviously reuse that number rather than increment past the last numbered file in the numbered sequence.)

Perhaps a better design altogether would be to use version control. Replacing the Excel file format with something less braindead would also simplify your life tremendously.